# Sharding with mongodb. Optimal way to write my query

Tags: mongodb, load-balancing, sharding, nosql

Let me try to explain my problem first, and then the solution I'm implementing. I have a collection of "events", which can be shared with specific users. I also have a collection of "users". Any user could share an event with any number of other users. When an event is shared with a user, it is seen in the home page of my website by that user (let's say that it is sorted by creation date to make it simple).

I want to use sharding to balance both my writes and my reads, and to be able to scale horizontally if needed. Before I thought of sharding, I had an events collection, which had an array of userIds within. Those userIds are the ones that can see the event. My query then was every event where the logged in user was contained within that array, sorted by creation date, limiting to my page size.

To implement sharding in this scenario, the obvious choice would be to somehow have the userId as shard key, as every event returned by my query has the userId within that embedded array. However, my userId is contained within an array, so that wouldn't work. I then though to have a new collection, with the following fields:

- userId: ObjectId (hashed shard key, to avoid monotony)
- eventId: ObjectId
- creationDate: Date

This way, I can run my query by userId, and have it go only to the corresponding shard. My problem of course with this solution, is that I now have eventIds instead of events, which is a somehow big document so I wouldn't want to have it redundantly as an embedded document within that collection (remember many users can be shared the same event).

To solve this, I think the correct solution would be to have the eventId be the shard key of the events collection (again, hashed to avoid monotony). I can then query the events collection by just those ids.

This raises two questions:

1. Is this the correct way to think about this particular problem. Is it a good solution?
2. As I now have several eventIds, let's just say five, and each one of them can be located in a different shard, which good be more performant: to have a single query looking for the five ids, or have five different queries looking for a single id each?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, this is correct way and solution is fine. Users sharded with userId and events sharded with eventId.
2. Latter one. five different queries searching single id, because then query goes to one shard. If you have single query what looks five ids same time ( $in:[]), it probably scatter to multiple shards.

Comment: Regarding the second point. You say having an ($in:[]) will make it scatter, which is absolutely true. However, doing five different queries will also "scatter" as each query could go to a different shard as well. What I mean is, the affected shards would be exactly the same ones in either case, wouldn't they?

Comment: Not fully.. But difference would be minimal. Sending query with only one id to shard, shard will find it from index very fast. Sending list of id's to every shard and shard need to go thru that index multiple time to find which of those id's are in "his" index. Multiple single id queries are parallel, one multiple id query is not.

Comment: I see. Having different queries actually makes my application logic easier, so if it's better that way, or even the same, it would be great. Should I not be concerned about any overhead of doing multiple queries against doing just one?

Comment: Mongodb is fast! Specially if you query is simple. Don't worry! If you design your sharding so that active data/indexes stays in memory (don't use hashed shard key if you have lot's of data) and you have enough memory (and use wiredTiger)